# How to input float numbers in HTML form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

my code is as follows:

```
<input type="number" min="4.50" max="9.90"  id="cpi" name="cpi" required="required" title="CPI" class="formfield3" />
```

CPI is a float value. But if I open  it in browser and input value which is the float number such as 7.89 then it shows message of 'Invalid Value'. How to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `number` type has a `step` value controlling which numbers are valid (along with `max` and `min`), which defaults to `1`. This value is also used by implementations for the stepper buttons (i.e. pressing up increases by `step`).

Simply change this value to whatever is appropriate. For money, two decimal places are probably expected:

```
<input type=number step=0.01 />
```

(I'd also set `min=0` if it can only be positive)

As usual, I'll add a quick note: remember that client-side validation is just a convenience to the user. You must also validate on the server-side!

Answer (score 9):

Set `step="any"`

```
<input type="number" min="4.50" max="9.90" step="any" id="cpi" name="cpi" required="required" title="CPI" class="formfield3" />
```

Comment: This is technically better than the approved answer, since the question does not specify any particular accuracy and can perhaps best be interpreted so that any number between the limits should be acceptable – and this is what `step="any"` does. But depending on the context, `step="0.01"` might correspond to what was intended or what is suitable.

Comment: When clicking the arrows to step up or down, it moves by 1.  But now I can type a float without validation going crazy.